# Structure of compact abelian group

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, lie-groups, abelian-groups, topological-groups

I would like to know if there's any structure theorem classifying all compact abelian groups, any reference is appreciated.

I do know there is a structure theorem for compact abelian Lie groups, and for locally compact abelian groups, however the first one is too specific and the second one is too general.

I know there are pro-finite groups, and Lie groups. Recently i discovered there are also Pro-Lie groups (which are not necessarily compact). Is every compact abelian group a direct product of these groups? If so, what can we say about compact Pro-Lie groups?

Thanks!

Comment: Because of Pontryagin duality, classifying all compact abelian groups is the same as classifying (abstract) abelian groups.

Comment: Is there any classifications of this groups?

Comment: No; it's a huge problem.

Comment: RIght, thanks! Then I guess that is why it is so hard to find a structure theorem for this groups.

Comment: There is a reasonable classification in the connected case.

Comment: Yes, The book of Loth's and Morris that egreg mentioned about says something about it. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: One fact that impressed me when learning about the structure of abelian groups and LCA groups: there are countable abelian groups G such that G is not isomorphic to a group of the form T x H, where T is a torsion group and H is torsion free    (See Fuchs's book Infinite Abelian Groups, Volume 1). Pontryagin duality then produces an example of a compact metric abelian group which cannot be written as a product of a connected group and a totally disconnected group.  So in general there's nothing as nice as the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: Very interesting, I will be looking for that thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start from the Wikipedia page on [Pontryagin duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality) which also has a few references on classical books on the subject, to which you may add [Loth's](https://books.google.it/books?id=SVfh5rgtxKEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=pontrjagin%20duality&hl=it&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=pontrjagin%20duality&f=false) and [Morris'](https://books.google.it/books?id=OmjMhK8hT20C&printsec=frontcover&dq=pontryagin%20duality&hl=it&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=pontryagin%20duality&f=false) books.

Pontryagin duality can be defined on the locally compact abelian groups, but restricts to a duality between discrete abelian groups and compact ones, so classifying compact abelian groups is the same as classifying (abstract) abelian groups, which is a huge problem, very far from being solved.